# Facebook PHP SDK 4.0 - Pulling page data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Wondering if anyone can help me out with being able to pull page data from Facebook? I am aware of the Graph API tool that I can use to get basic data (user name, cover photo, address, etc) like this:

http://graph.facebook.com/318251298186105

However, I need to pull more data than that, such as band members, picture, and other data available in the Graph API reference (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page).

I will already have the page ID--I just need to get the page data using the page ID, if possible. So far I have downloaded the SDK and put the Facebook folder in the same directory as my PHP file, fb-pull.php. Then the fb-pull.php has this code:

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;

// init app with app id (APPID) and secret (SECRET)
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('MYAPPID','MYAPPSECRET');

/* make the API call */
$request = new FacebookRequest(
    $session,
     'GET',
     '/318251298186105'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */ 
//not sure how to output results?
?>
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing as this example comes from the Facebook dev site.

If anyone can help me with this code to help me just pull some data from FB pages, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the PHP SDK (v4.0.x), you can do the same thing using:

```
<?php

// include required files form Facebook SDK

// added in v4.0.5
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );

// added in v4.0.0
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );

// added in v4.0.5
use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;

// added in v4.0.0
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;

// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'xxx','yyy' );

// get app access_token
$session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();

// make request to Facebook 
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/318251298186105' );
$response = $request->execute();
// get response as array
$content = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();

// output html
?>

<h1><?= $content['name'] ?> (<?= $content['id'] ?>)</h1>
<p><img src="http://graph.facebook.com/<?= $content['id'] ?>/picture?width=180&height=180" /></p>
<p>About: <?= $content['about'] ?></p>
<p>Bio: <?= $content['bio'] ?></p>
<p>Band Members: <?= $content['band_members'] ?></p>
<p>Genre: <?= $content['genre'] ?></p>
```

Comment: Thanks! I added your code (along with my app id), but I just get an error when visiting the page now: Fatal error: Class 'Facebook\Entities\AccessToken' not found in /[project-root]/fb/Facebook/FacebookSession.php on line 74

Comment: I used these requires above the code you gave: require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
        require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
        require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
        require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
        require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
        require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
        require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
        require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. If anyone else needs code for this, here is a sample page I built that will accept a page ID or alias and give you ID and other info. You can pull more info from the page by just adding more variables following the format.

#### Enter Facebook page URL or page ID (Ex: "aerosmith" or 58153618123):

http://www.facebook.com/

---

```
        /*** Process result from form using Graph API ***/
        if(isset($_POST['fb_id'])) {//if form was submitted   

            //get the url and pass it into the URL
            //you will probably want to do some more validation on the $_POST var
            $url="https://graph.facebook.com/" . $_POST['fb_id'];

            //below gets the data into the $content object
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
            $content = curl_exec($ch);
            $content = json_decode($content);         
        ?>

        <!-- now just print out the data as desired -->
        <h1><?= $content->name ?> (<?= $content->id ?>)</h1>
        <p><img src="http://graph.facebook.com/<?= $content->id ?>/picture?width=180&height=180" /></p>
        <p>About: <?= $content->about ?></p>
        <p>Bio: <?= $content->bio ?></p>
        <p>Band Members: <?= $content->band_members ?></p>
        <p>Genre: <?= $content->genre ?></p>

        <?php } ?>

    </body>
</html>
```